# Replace the pipe character “|” with line blank space

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to solve a code challenge about Morse Code, the idea is to:

- **Receive**: `morse_text = '.... ..|--. ..- -.-- ...'`
- **Return**: `'HI GUYS'`
- But I am getting `'HIGUYS'`

where the pipe should be converted into a space between the 2 words. So far I got:

```
def decode(morse_text)
  # TODO: Decode the morse text
  morse_text = morse_text.tr("|", " ")
  array = morse_text.split(" ").map { |word| encode_word.invert[word].upcase }
  array.join
end

def encode_word
  morse_code = {
    "a" => ".-",
    "b" => "-...",
    "c" => "-.-.",
    "d" => "-..",
    "e" => ".",
    "f" => "..-.",
    "g" => "--.",
    "h" => "....",
    "i" => "..",
    "j" => ".---",
    "k" => "-.-",
    "l" => ".-..",
    "m" => "--",
    "n" => "-.",
    "o" => "---",
    "p" => ".--.",
    "q" => "--.-",
    "r" => ".-.",
    "s" => "...",
    "t" => "-",
    "u" => "..-",
    "v" => "...-",
    "w" => ".--",
    "x" => "-..-",
    "y" => "-.--",
    "z" => "--..",
    " " => "|"
  }
end
```

I'm struggling in convert the pipe into a blank space so I can get the desire result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're converting the pipe to a space which means you lose the unique separator for words and treat it as just a standard separator of characters. Instead, split by the pipe and operate on an array of words:

```
def decode(morse_text)
  # Split the morse code into an array of encoded words
  encoded_words = morse_text.split('|')

  # Decode each word letter by letter
  decoded_words = encoded_words.map do |word|
    word.split(' ').map { |letter| encode_word.invert[letter].upcase }
  end

  # Join each decoded word into a string
  joined_words = decoded_words.map { |word| word.join }

  # Join each word into a single string
  decoded_text = joined_words.join(' ')
end
```

The result is:

```
decode('.... ..|--. ..- -.-- ...')
=> "HI GUYS"
```

Comment: I suggest you compute a hash `mapping = encode_word.invert.transform_values(&:upcase)
 #=> {".-"=>"A", "-..."=>"B",...,"--.."=>"Z", "|"=>" "}` just once, rather than computing for every string inside the block. Also, if you write `encoded_words = morse_text.split(/ +|(?=\|)|(?<=\|)/) #=> ["....", "..", "|", "--.", "..-", "-.--", "..."]`, you can go directly to `encoded_words.map { |word| mapping[word] }.join #=> "HI GUYS"`.

Comment: Lots of ways to skin the cat, I just wanted to make as little change as possible. I like your answer too!

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that employs a hash for making substitutions.

If the variable `morse_code` holds your hash, with the additional key_value pair `""=>" "`, compute the following hash.

```
decoding_map = morse_code.invert.transform_values(&:upcase)
  #=> {".-"=>"A", "-..."=>"B", "-.-."=>"C", "-.."=>"D", "."=>"E",
  #    ...
  #    "-..-"=>"X", "-.--"=>"Y", "--.."=>"Z", "|"=>" ", , " "=>""}
```

Then

```
morse_text = '.... ..|--. ..- -.-- ...'

morse_text.gsub(/[| ]|[.-]+/, decoding_map)
  #=> "HI GUYS"
```

The regular expression reads, "match a pipe or space or a mix of one or more periods or hyphens".